# How to install pynbody on MacOS

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install the pynbody package for python.
I run `pip3 install pynbody`, but the command fails.
It says:

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pynbody which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Before it gives the error:

```
error: Command "/usr/local/bin/gcc-10 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -I/private/var/folders/5q/xc22bbms0qjdgmpsv2188ydh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-q66c57aj/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c pynbody/gravity/_gravity.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/pynbody/gravity/_gravity.o -fopenmp" failed with exit status 1
```

I have MacOS 11.0.1 and python 3.9.0 and pip 20.2.4.
I can install other packages via pip such as numpy.
How can I install pynbody on MacOS?
(The same procedure worked on ubuntu.)
The Xcode developer tools are installed.

Comment: Please show the text of the entire error. I tried to install the thing limiting virtual memory to 500 megabytes — the compilation failed with error "not enough memory" and "ERROR: Could not build wheels for pynbody which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly". I increased virtual memory to 2G and installation finished. I mean — there could different reasons for failure, we cannot guess and need to see the entire error message.

Comment: The problem was solved by cloning directly from github
"git clone https://github.com/pynbody/pynbody.git".
Then building manually "python3 setup.py install" (without using pip).